# Google Login issue in React js

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I am New to reactJS and I am trying to google login with my ReactJS app but facing problem that when I am clicking on google login button then googleLogin function calls multiple times and responded multiple times.
I am trying to resolve this by binding button click event but it effect please review my code and suggest any solution.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import google from './google.png'  
    import config from '../config';

    class GoogleLogin extends Component{
       constructor(props) {
           super(props)
       }

       componentDidMount(){
           (function() {
               var e = document.createElement("script");
               e.type = "text/javascript";
               e.async = true;
               e.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=gPOnLoad";
               var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
               t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
           })();    
       }

       //Triggering login for google
       googleLogin = () => {
           let response = null;
           window.gapi.auth.signIn({
               callback: function(authResponse) {
                   this.googleSignInCallback( authResponse )
               }.bind( this ),
               clientid: config.google, //Google client Id
               cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
               requestvisibleactions: "http://schema.org/AddAction",
               scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email"
           });
       }

       googleSignInCallback = (e) => {
           console.log( e )
           if (e["status"]["signed_in"]) {
               window.gapi.client.load("plus", "v1", function() {
                   if (e["access_token"]) {
                       this.getUserGoogleProfile( e["access_token"] )
                   } else if (e["error"]) {
                       console.log('Import error', 'Error occured while importing data')
                   }
               }.bind(this));
           } else {
               console.log('Oops... Error occured while importing data')
           }
       }

       getUserGoogleProfile = accesstoken => {
           var e = window.gapi.client.plus.people.get({
               userId: "me"
           });
           e.execute(function(e) {
               if (e.error) {
                   console.log(e.message);
                   console.log('Import error - Error occured while importing data')
                   return

               } else if (e.id) {
                   //Profile data
                   alert("Successfull login from google : "+ e.displayName )
                   console.log( e );
                   return;
               }
           }.bind(this));
       }

       render(){
           return(
               <img src={google} title="google login" alt="google" onClick={ () => this.googleLogin() }/>
           )
       }
    }

export default GoogleLogin;
```